# Pomodoro clock: resume button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I am making a Pomodoro clock. I took a `clock` object, added `start`, `pause`, `resume` functions. To run the clock repeatedly in the `start` function I added two variable `s` and `b` to keep the original time of session and break. So, in the `pause` function when I am deleting the timer the original time of session and break is getting deleted. so
`resume` function clock is staring from the beginning. Now, how to write the `pause` function in the right way to make the `resume`?

This is JSfiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/sajibBD/f18nh323/3/

Thanks in advance!

```
var Clock = {
sessionSeconds: 0,
breakSeconds: 0,

start: function () {
    var self = this;
    var s = this.sessionSeconds + 1;
    var b = this.breakSeconds + 1;

    this.interval = setInterval(function () {
        if (s > 0) {
            s -= 1;
            $('#state').text('Session');
            $("#min").text(Math.floor(s / 60 % 60));
            $("#sec").text(parseInt(s % 60));
        } else if (b > 0) {
            b -= 1;
            $('#state').text('Break');
            $("#min").text(Math.floor(b / 60 % 60));
            $("#sec").text(parseInt(b % 60));
        } else if (b === 0) {
            s = self.sessionSeconds + 1;
            b = self.breakSeconds + 1;
        }

        var min = $("#min").text();
        var sec = $("#sec").text();

        if (min.length === 1) {
            $("#min").text('0' + min);
        }
        if (sec.length === 1) {
            $("#sec").text('0' + sec);
        }

    }, 1000)
},

pause: function () {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    delete this.interval;
},

resume: function () {
    if (!this.interval) this.start();
},
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

http://jsfiddle.net/f18nh323/5/

```
var Clock = {
sessionSeconds: 0,
breakSeconds: 0,

start: function () {
    var self = this;
    var s = this.sessionSeconds + 1;

    var b = this.breakSeconds + 1;

    this.interval = setInterval(function () {

        if (s > 0) {
            s -= 1;
            $('#state').text('Session');
            $("#min").text(Math.floor(s / 60 % 60));
            $("#sec").text(parseInt(s % 60));
        } else if (b > 0) {
            b -= 1;
            $('#state').text('Break');
            $("#min").text(Math.floor(b / 60 % 60));
            $("#sec").text(parseInt(b % 60));
        } else if (b === 0) {
            s = self.sessionSeconds + 1;
            b = self.breakSeconds + 1;
        }


        self.sessionSeconds = s;
        var min = $("#min").text();
        var sec = $("#sec").text();



        if (min.length === 1) {
            $("#min").text('0' + min);
        }
        if (sec.length === 1) {
            $("#sec").text('0' + sec);
        }


    }, 1000)
},

pause: function () {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    delete this.interval;
},

resume: function () {
    if (!this.interval) this.start();
},
```

}

Comment: I think you didn't check. session time is not repeating. break time is  being repeated again and again!